# Vim - building Latex files

Tags: vim, latex, windows-xp

I have a latex file (.tex) which I'm editing in vim. Usually, I just go into cmd and type `pdflatex my-file.tex`, hope for the best, and a .pdf pops out :)

What would I need to change in Vim, to use Vim's "make option". So, I can just do :make, and let Vim build my .tex files for me. Also, I'd like it to display the output in a new buffer to the right?

Can anyone give me some pointers on this? I just started using that feature (:make in Vim).

EDIT: Bonus points :) for tips that handle the problems mentioned by Sebastian, as well.

Answer (score 5):

I personally have the following in [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/Eckankar/rcfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L273):

```
autocmd FileType tex setlocal makeprg=pdflatex\ --shell-escape\ '%'
```

That will let you `:make` in order to run `pdflatex`.

It is not perfect, however:

- It doesn't take care of compiling BiBTeX, graphviz, etc... for you.
- It doesn't compile twice if needed.
- `--shell-escape` is a slightly dangerous option that allows the document to call any program, but it is needed in order to compile documents using `dot2texi`. (Embedded graphviz.)
- Possibly more.

For more complicated documents, I tend to use the [LaTeX Makefile](http://code.google.com/p/latex-makefile/). It's quite large and does quite a lot of things, but usually it'll do what you want automatically with no or only minor modifications.

Comment: +1 Well, it's a start where to look ('makeprg'). It would be cool if it could take care of references as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would just write a Makefile, and leave my Vim settings alone.  In general the makefiles I use  are pretty dumb, but even they take care of BiBTeX, and I usually compile three times.  You can do much better if you put more effort in.  An example of "less effort" is

```
myfoo.pdf: myfoo.tex
         pdflatex myfoo
         pdflatex myfoo
         bibtex myfoo
         pdflatex myfoo
```

(except you need to use tabs, not spaces, and I haven't tested the above at all, and I don't use pdflatex myself, so expect bugs).  If you don't like Make (and who really does), then you can use some other similar build tool, and then set `makeprg` to point to that.  I've never tried that though.

Comment: +1 Will look into it, thanks Adrian! I don't care much about the dumbness of the tool, just as long as it works and doesn't require much effort from my part.

Comment: When you do it, please post the actual working code, for the benefit of anyone who finds this post in the future.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding re-running latex, consider `latexmk`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [vim-latex / latex-suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) – it solves all your problems :)